# SQL - Table not found after backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I saved a SQL table before deleting some information from it with the sql statment:

```
select * into x_table from y_table
```

After doing some operations, I want to get back some information from the table I saved with the query above. Unfortunately, MS SQL Server MGMTS shows an error saying that the table does not exist.

However, when I put the drop statement, the table is recognized - and the table is not underlined.

Any idea why this table is recognized by the drop table statement and not the select from statement. This seems strange for me.

EDIT:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Show us your errors.

Comment: Are you sure you're creating a table and not just a temp table? Please post more of your SQL statement.

Comment: Did you actually execute the statement and get an error or do you just see the red squiggly underline / mouse over error. SSMS is very good at parsing your statements, but there are lots of ways you can combine DDL statements in which it doesn't think the same as you do

Comment: select * into X from mytable where condition1 = 40 and condition2 between '20160401' and '20160630'

Comment: I dont want to execute the drop table statment so i will lose my table. however when executing the select statment i get an error !

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error in the edited post. Thank you

Comment: Is this x_table or y_table you are trying to select from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116704/discussion-between-zeph-and-user2233979).

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the table isn't underlined in your `drop table` command because its name is still in your IntelliSense cache. Select Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache in SSMS (or just press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`R`) and see if the table name is underlined then.

**Edit:**

Another possibility is that your `drop table` command might be in the same batch as another statement that creates the table, in which case SSMS won't underline it because it knows that even though the table doesn't exist now, it *will* exist by the time that command is executed. For instance:

[image: Illustration of IntelliSense behavior with table names]

None of the tables `one`, `two`, or `three` existed in my database when I took this screenshot. If I highlight line 6 and try to run it by itself, it will fail. Yet you can see that `two` is not underlined on line 6 because SSMS can see that if I run the whole script, the table will be created on line 5. On the other hand, `three` *is* underlined on line 9 because I commented out the code that would have created it on line 8.

All of that said, I think we might be making too much of this problem. If you try to `select` from a table and SQL Server tells you it doesn't exist, then it doesn't exist. You can't rely on IntelliSense to tell you that it does; the two examples above are probably not the only ways that IntelliSense might mislead you about the current status of a table.

If you want the simplest way to know whether an object with a given name (like `x_table`) exists, just use:

```
select object_id('x_table');
```

If this query returns null, `x_table` doesn't exist, regardless of what IntelliSense is telling you. If it returns non-null, then there *is* some object out there with that name, and then the real question is why your `select` statement is failing. And to answer that, I'd need to see the statement.

Comment: I tried this suggestion based on other SOF question but no chance. the table is not listed on the SSMS tables which is strange. I'm 100% sure i have executed the statment.

Comment: The sidebar on SSMS will not refresh unless you refresh it. Right click on the database where you are executing your command, and then click Refresh at the bottom.

Comment: I expanded with a new idea or two, @user2233979. Arthur D also makes a very good point.

Comment: select object_id('x_table') returns null!

Answer (score -1):

A lot of posts like this, you have to copy in 2 statements :

CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;